# Not supported or did I do something wrong?

Tags: html, css

So I was reading the [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#toggle-notation) in the W3C's website. In Section 8.2, it introduces the `toggle()` expression, which can cycling through different values instead of using the same value for all children.

And I gave it [a try](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/7J3Qk/):

```
div{
    font-style: toggle(italic, normal);
    font-style: -webkit-toggle(italic, normal);  //Don't know if needed or not,
    font-style: -moz-toggle(italic, normal);     //Put it there in case
}​
```

But clearly it is not working. I am wondering if it is not supported right now, or did I do something wrong. Section 8.1 's `calc()` is supported, and section 8.3 's `attr()` is also supported, therefore I think this is also supported.

I have checked [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=toggle), but no luck.

Comment: have you read this `The ‘toggle()’ notation is not allowed to be nested; nor may it contain ‘attr()’ or ‘calc()’ notations. Declarations containing such constructs are invalid.`

Comment: @diEcho - Yes, and I didn't do anything like `toggle(toggle(...,...),...)` in my code.

Comment: I didnt get why you mention `attr` and `calc` in you question.

Comment: @diEcho - Because if section 8.1 and 8.3 are both supported, then there is a high probability that 8.2 will also be supported (by Chrome).

Comment: For the record, section 8.3's `attr()` in V&U level 3 is *not* supported by any browsers. Browsers only support [CSS2.1's `attr()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#x18) which is far more limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think it has any support yet: http://css3clickchart.com/#toggle and no mention of it on the quirksmode tables.. or is it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference).

Comment: Well, then it looks like it is currently not supported.